# How to pass GloVE embeddings through CNN?

Tags: pytorch, dataset, word-embedding, data-preprocessing

I have a pre-trained CNN and would like to see the model's confidence on some simple imdb prediction. For example, I have the sentence "I love this movie", I would like to throw it into my CNN and get the {"pos": x, "neg": y} values.

So far this is what I have:

I have loaded the `glove.840B.300d` into a dictionary, where `{'word': GloVE embedding}`

and I have the following pre-trained torch model:

```
CNN(
(embs): Embedding(43036, 300)
  (linear_input): Linear(in_features=300, out_features=100, bias=True)
  (conv1): Conv1d(100, 100, kernel_size=(3,), stride=(1,))
  (fc_hidden): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=100, bias=True)
  (fc_output): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=1, bias=True)
)
```

How would I insert my sentence into the model to get a the desired prediction from it?